# Is it possible to think of the number e as a fraction of pi?

Tags: calculus, pi

$20$ years ago I did my Calculus $101$ "term paper" on this (Okay, what else would you call it? It was more of a story problem that we presented to the class, but as everyone else chose a practical applied story problem from the book, I was the only one to tackle a theoretical problem.... )

I remember yes, you can, e is just a fraction multiple of pi or something like that..., but I can't find out/remember exactly how to write it....

Thanks

Comment: I think it is unknown whether e/pi is irrational or not (although most people think it is irrational)

Comment: If by “fraction” you mean “rational number” (integer divided by integer), then it is unknown. If by “fraction” you mean “a real number divided by a real number”,m then the answer is “yes”, because $e=\left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)\pi$.

Comment: FWIW, this [Sage / Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtTkEOgzAMu_OKHFupYozjJKa9hIqVlEXTCpSAtN8vLUhc5kusxLG9QQMIF5iocF64GwNTWLG3PnaOaQxq08UUKbByPjFk_tpz8RCCSVr06MGqngbipakrfStA8KK5Ft9r1e6XvNzfxdrAod-H1vnsxwhkgIECYFg_4s8oaaW02zAOGHhR-gjIfgZmCeGyW2zqM2C08kOj0qcmZyZbA0Hx_-QE8jC3Ndxz9TMj4Rmxe_8ACVlbqQ==&lang=sage) prints rational approximations of $e/\pi$ from its [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should be more precise as "fraction" is an imprecise term. Is $e$ a *rational* multiple of $\pi$, or, equivalently, can you write $\frac{e} {\pi} = \frac ab$ where $a, b$ are integers sharing no common factors other than $1$? This is an open question, answer unknown. It is strongly suspected to be "no" (that $\frac{e} {\pi}$ is irrational) but without a conclusive proof one way or the other, the question remains open.

However, there is a very similar question about whether the product $e\pi$ is rational. This is also an open question. But the two quantities cannot *both* be rational (can you see why)?

Just for interest, there are similar open questions about $e+\pi$ and $e-\pi$, but again, *both* of these can't be simultaneously rational.

In fact of these four: $e+\pi, e-\pi, e\pi, \frac e{\pi}$, it is quite easy to show that *at most one* can be rational. Again, this is left as an exercise for you (should it interest you).

Comment: to try and be more precise I think it was something like e = (some coefficient) pi. (though it may have relied on some other identities or whatnot...  this was nearly 20 years ago and I did not pursue a mathematics education)

Comment: @obiwan Yes, but characterising that "some coefficient" makes all the difference in the world. :) By the way, try out the little challenge in my last paragraph. It's rather fun and satisfying. All you need is very basic algebra and logic.

Comment: Well if both the decimal expansions are infinite, it follows that the sums of 2 infinite progressions would also be infinite, i'm not quite in the mode or do I have time to comtemplete if this by itself is sufficient to deny their rationality, but it suffices at the really speedy and quick level my brain is ready for right now.  I think the same logic applies for the product and quotients too.... well to put it simply, any infinite decimal expansion, when speaking of exact fractional representations, would require also an infinitely big ..... sequence of sums....

Comment: @obiwan. OK. $0.3333....$ is a decimal expansion that is infinite. As is $0.66666....$. Their sum is $0.9999... = 1$, which is finite (and rational). So this is a counterexample to what you wrote (it's really just $\frac 13 + \frac 23 = 1$. Not convinced? How about $3.1415926535...$ and $0.85840734...$? Both looking nice and random and infinite? But their sum ($\pi + 4-\pi$) is simply $4$, an integer. Looking at the decimal expansion of numbers to draw conclusions like this is hazardous.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iπ}$ = -1

I had to rely on a mathamatics friend, but it sure does look familiar I just had to have a little help with my memory....